# Error fetching data from database though Json

Tags: android

I'm having problem regarding fetching of data from MySQL through json. I've tried a lot but couldn't catch the issue that i'm facing. I'm trying to display list fetched from the database and parsed through json in ListView. Below is the code. Please help me out!

**GetAll.java**

```
package com.example.energy;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GetAll extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/android/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GetAll.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            GetAll.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.listitem, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

**JSONParser.java**

```
package com.example.energy;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**get_all_products.php**

```
<?php

$response=array();

require_once('/db_connect.php');

$db= new DB_CONNECT();

$db->construct();
$db->connect();

$result=mysql_query("Select * from files") or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $response["products"]=array();

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["id"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
       // $product["price"] = $row["price"];
      //  $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
      //  $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];

        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}



?>
```

**Error displaying on stack trace**

```
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488): Process: com.example.energy, PID: 1488
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at com.example.energy.GetAll$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(GetAll.java:131)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at com.example.energy.GetAll$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(GetAll.java:1)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-11 06:59:32.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     ... 4 more
03-11 06:59:33.803: I/Choreographer(1488): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-11 06:59:34.703: I/Choreographer(1488): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-11 06:59:35.983: I/Choreographer(1488): Skipped 138 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-11 06:59:38.313: I/Choreographer(1488): Skipped 240 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-11 06:59:38.783: I/Choreographer(1488): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.energy.GetAll has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b1d86d70 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at com.example.energy.GetAll$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(GetAll.java:118)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at com.example.energy.GetAll.onCreate(GetAll.java:58)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-11 06:59:40.323: E/WindowManager(1488):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 06:59:40.333: I/Choreographer(1488): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-11 07:04:14.003: I/Process(1488): Sending signal. PID: 1488 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What is your stack trace ?

Comment: Please copy paste your whole stack trace in your question.

Comment: Please check my edited question.

Comment: Why don't u just, copy an paste your stack trace ?

Comment: Im sorry, but this is what i've done Sir.

Comment: you want me to add error in question and not a screen shot?

Comment: Yea. Pls add the error in your question

Comment: line number 131 in your doInBackground you are getting NullPointor. check your code on that line.

Comment: I think you have issue in this line JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params); json is null.

Comment: Which is line number 131 ?

Comment: My precious application works fine and doesn't give me any sort of error on that line #jaydroider.

Comment: as @M.S.P asked which is line no 131 pls specify.

Comment: line number 131 is "Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());"

Comment: so that means, your json is null

Comment: Now what does that mean? How do i solve it?

Comment: @Mikka what i have told u in previous comment that your json is null. Try to debug with makehttprequest.

Comment: #jaydroider, I appreciate that! but please could you tell me how do i solve it?

Comment: Try to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

This clearly indicates that your Json value is returning null. Hence, you need to debug your whole project.

1. **Start from your php script and check whether the responses are correct.**
   Here, check whether your Php script results are correct. if possible, use `die(json_encode($response));` instead if echoing it.
2. **Assuming that your Php Scripts are working good,** start debugging your android code. As you know, in-order to pass data in background method, you need to use `params[]` in the `AsyncTask`. Pass your data when you call your inherited  `AsyncTask` and `Log` it everywhere.

Since, your Log returns a null pointer, I presume that you have a Logical error in your Parser or your Php Script.

**P.S** : This may take sometime, But doing it step by step, will surely result you some good ripened fruits.